# Check if different names of file is in folder

Tags: python

Let's say I have a file name which I want to see if in a folder. I can then use `os.path` to search for it in a folder, for example:

```
import os.path

file_name = "file1.txt"

if os.path.isfile(file_name) is False:
    print("File name was not found")
```

This is fairly simple. However, if I know that the file can take different names, for example:

```
file_names = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt", "file4.txt"]
```

Then I could probably do something "ugly" by saying:

```
if os.path.isfile(file_names[0]) is False or if os.path.isfile(file_names[1]) is False or if os.path.isfile(file_names[2]) is False or if os.path.isfile(file_names[3]) is False:
    print("File name was not found")
```

And I can't seem to figure out if a loop is gonna do the trick, since it should only print if ALL statements are false, and not just print if one is not found (i.e. it will at least always find three there isn't there). So yeah, how can this be done more beautifully ?

Comment: On a phone so untested: `if all([not os.isfile(name) for name in file_names]):`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if not any(os.path.isfile(file_name) for file_name in file_names):
    print("Not found!")
```

Or, more concisely:

```
if not any(map(os.path.isfile, file_names)):
    print("Not found!")
```

This says: "if *at least one* of these files exists, *do not* print `Not found`".

Comment: This is the part that confused me, because the code and the OP's intended output conflict over any/all in the question

Comment: @roganjosh, the very first edition of my answer was also using `all`, LOL :D

Comment: Yeah, something is amiss in there :) I _think_ it's `all` they wanted but not sure